# linux gateway using keepalived

Tags: routing, debian-jessie, keepalived

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFouN.png)
Dear, I'm using 2 linux as my gateway of a subnet. Here I want to using keepalived service, But ip routing looked strange. From the router it couldn't find a route to the subnet. Tracerout looked like below:

**traceroute to  192.168.1.100** 

**1 10.0.1.1**

**2 10.0.1.253 (the master node)**

**3 * * * * ***

How can I make it work?

Comment: Is there any NAT / firewalling happening on the linux gateways? Does it work without the keepalived part, i.e. with just a single gateway? You give very little information.

Comment: emmmmm...Client firewall caused this problem...